# When I try post a message on my fb page using PHP SDK i see "Graph returned an error: Invalid parameter"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post simple message on my facebook post wall, I try to use PHP SDK v5. The documentation about sdk witch is on Facebook Developers is not so clear for me, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

When i try run this script with posting a message a get an error message " Graph returned an error: Invalid parameter"

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

//use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken; 
//use Facebook\GraphUser;
//use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '************',
    'app_secret' => '****************************',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
        ]);
$page_id = '****************'; 
// HERE IS LONG LIVED ACCESS TOKEN WITCH I GENERATED MANUALY 
$access_token =  '*********************************'; 
// HERE IS A CODE WITH GET A POSTS FROM MY WALL AND PRINT IT IN A MY WEBSITE
$object = $fb->get('.$page_id.'/feed', $access_token); 
$posts_array = $object->getDecodedBody();

print_r($posts_array['data']); 

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/'.$page_id.'/feed', $linkData, $access_token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I found the problem. In the $linkData array the link parameter is a problem. When i deleted it, every think works. Topic to close.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. In the $linkData array the link parameter is a problem. When i deleted it, every think works. Topic to close.